# How to project column name and value from JSON in KQL?

Tags: json, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have the following 'SetOfSignals' in KQL (using `mv-expand`):

```
"SetOfSignals": {
    "name": "CompanyName",
    "signals": [
        {
            "name": "AmbientAirTemperature",
            "unit": "C",
            "dataType": "Float32",
            "values": [
                "11.5"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "AverageEnergyConsumption",
            "unit": "W",
            "dataType": "Float32",
            "values": [
                "780.0"
            ]
        }
}
```

and now I want to project the signal names with corresponding values.

I want it to look like this:

| ... | AmbientAirTemperature | AverageEnergyConsumption |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 11.5 | 780.0 |

but using something like `| extend AmbientAirTemperature = signals.name` doesn't works since there are multiple strings within "signals" with the name "name".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(SetOfSignals:dynamic)
[
    dynamic
    (
        {
            "name": "CompanyName",
            "signals": [
                {
                    "name": "AmbientAirTemperature",
                    "unit": "C",
                    "dataType": "Float32",
                    "values": [
                        "11.5"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AverageEnergyConsumption",
                    "unit": "W",
                    "dataType": "Float32",
                    "values": [
                        "780.0"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    )
]
| mv-apply signal = SetOfSignals.signals on 
  (
    summarize make_bag(bag_pack(tostring(signal.name), signal.values[0]))
  )
| project-away SetOfSignals
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_)
```

| AmbientAirTemperature | AverageEnergyConsumption |
| --- | --- |
| 11.5 | 780.0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA71STWuDQBC9B/IfFk8KiZiW0hLoIYT22B4S6EFCGHUq27gfrKvFfvz37qoksSqhl47I7s68mTfzmAS0%20aIM3Q3q59cNTTlk%20TKpODAae9NJOJ0QY62jebjNYe3zdLXmGBQ6S%20KsBZPAqyf7nP3C5A2JgYXdyEDBXuEViyhyvaJqi0yiAl2oHsUxq%20BU1%202MIhIz/raSde3HTIC%20vhrFlpAVONL3EbRY%20DfOcHzXd38PcF2UoDRjp/jAUaXVWvC8YFJTwS%20q8PJ/KtzeBX7wBxm6rjNEGzGbaJxfhJVzkDKrSLNE5J6c763frhYRnNi8dlGNQAwU/UDC4ID7CFLX/HsJ8cHVIteK8tRtUn0rsjdry/vNrGGw8zxbyrMtSCXeMNZzeIeqw26DaDNAI7EEBa8p7NX7ARileY5pAwAA)